# How to add proxy to Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm behind a proxy server and I need to build Qt Android application. I have proxy's settings.

Is there a way how can I add proxy settings to Qt Creator during the building process?

**Compilation Output**

```
NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
KERBEROS authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.jar'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
```

Comment: do you have the `https_proxy` environment variable set on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have set it, but continuing giving the same errors.

Comment: what authentication scheme is your proxy using? Looks like NTLM/Kerberos, lots of open source software struggles with proxy authentication. CNTLM is often useful

Comment: I'm behind of Forefront TMG proxy